# How do I load my extension on chrome startup?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have developed a google chrome extension and I have a **badge** on the icon that displays a number.

When I start the browser the badge is not displayed. So I think I have to load the extension when chrome browser was started.

Is that possible?

Comment: Where and when do you calculate that badge? If you put the code into beginning of a background page it would run during new browser window creation.

Comment: thanks that actually solves my problem :) post this as an answer and I will except it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Code in a background page is executed when a new browser window is created.